# Expanding composite function one in terms of the other in a power series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, taylor-expansion

if I have a composite function $\rho(V(x))$, is it possible to write $\rho$ in a power series as follows,
$$\rho(V(x)) \sim a_{0} + a_{1}V(x) + a_{2}(V(x))^{2} +.... +a_{n}(V(x))^{n}$$. Is this correct , Does this make sense and mathematically correct in any way? In short , I want to express $\rho$ as a function of $V$ in a power series. Please also provide some reference if there is any. I am from physics background sorry if my question looks utterly wrong.

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem , note that you want here $\rho$ to be $n$-times differentials and in order for the error to be small you need $V(x)$ to be small (but how small depends on $\rho$)

Comment: Thanks if want this to infinite series...Can I do this ? Is it mathematically correct? @s.harp

Comment: The relevant keywords are: 1. Analytic function, 2. Power series, 3. Convergence radius of a power series. Analytic functions are very special functions, but a large number of functions appearing in classical mechanics are analytic.